# Big files uploading (WebException: The connection was closed unexpectedly)

Tags: c#, .net, file, upload, httpwebrequest

**UPDATED**

See post [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060966/big-files-uploading-webexception-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly/1066265#1066265) below.

There is a need to upload a file to the web automatically (without browser). Host - [Mini File Host v1.2](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mini+file+host) (if this does matter). Didn't find specific api in documentation, so at first i sniffed browser requests in Firebug as follows :

```
Params : do
Value : verify
POST /upload.php?do=verify HTTP/1.1
Host: webfile.ukrwest.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; ru; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8 (.NET CLR 4.0.20506)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://filehoster.awardspace.com/index.php
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------27368237179714
Content-Length: 445

-----------------------------27368237179714
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="Test.file"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

12345678901011121314151617sample text
-----------------------------27368237179714
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="descr"


-----------------------------27368237179714
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pprotect"


-----------------------------27368237179714--
```

Here we can see parameter, headers, content type and chunks of information (1 - file name and type, 2 - file contents, 3 - additional params - description and password, not necessarily applied).
So i've created a class that emulates such a behaviour step by step : HttpWebRequest on the url, apply needed parameters to request, form request strings with StringBuilder and convert them to byte arrays, read a file using FileStream, putting all that stuff to MemoryStream and then writing it to request (took major part of a code from an article at CodeProject where it uploads a file to Rapidshare host).
 Neat and tidy, but... It doesn't seem to work :(. As result it returns initial upload page, not a result page with links i could parse and present to a user... 
Here are main methods of an Uploader class :

```
// Step 1 - request creation 
 private HttpWebRequest GetWebrequest(string boundary)
 {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://filehoster.awardspace.com/index.php?do=verify");
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = _cookies;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; ru; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8 (.NET CLR 4.0.20506)";
            httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://filehoster.awardspace.com/index.php";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = -1;
            //httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
            //httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            //httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = new Version(1,1);
            //httpWebRequest.SendChunked = true;
            //httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            //httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            return httpWebRequest;
}
// Step 2 - first message part (before file contents)
private string GetRequestMessage(string boundary, string FName, string description, string password)
{    
            System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append("--");
            stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
            stringBuilder.Append("upfile");
            stringBuilder.Append("\"; filename=\"");
            stringBuilder.Append(FName);
            stringBuilder.Append("\"");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
// Step 4 - additional request parameters. Step 3 - reading file is in method below
private string GetRequestMessageEnd(string boundary)
{    
            System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"descr\"");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("Default description");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pprotect\"");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append("");
            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
            stringBuilder.Append("--");
            //stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            //stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
            //stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
// Main method
public string ProcessUpload(string FilePath, string description, string password)
{
            // Chosen file information
            FileSystemInfo _file = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            // Random boundary generation
            DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.Now;
            long l2 = dateTime2.Ticks;
            string _generatedBoundary = "----------" + l2.ToString("x");
            // Web request creation
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = GetWebrequest(_generatedBoundary);
            // Main app block - form and send request
            using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                byte[] bArr1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + _generatedBoundary + "\r\n");
                // Generating pre-content post message
                string firstPostMessagePart = GetRequestMessage(_generatedBoundary, _file.Name, description, password);
                // Writing first part of request
                byte[] bArr2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(firstPostMessagePart);
                Stream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                memStream.Write(bArr1, 0, bArr1.Length);
                memStream.Write(bArr2, 0, bArr2.Length);
                // Writing file
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                // Generating end of a post message
                string secondPostMessagePart = GetRequestMessageEnd(_generatedBoundary);
                byte[] bArr3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secondPostMessagePart);
                memStream.Write(bArr3, 0, bArr3.Length);
                // Preparing to send
                httpWebRequest.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
                fileStream.Close();

                Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

                memStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
                memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                memStream.Close();
                // Sending request
                requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }
            // Delay (?)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            // Getting response
            string strResponse = "";
            using (Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream/*, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)*/))
            {
                strResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return strResponse;
}
```

Plays with ProtocolVersion (1.0, 1.1), AllowAutoRedirect (true/false), even known ServicePoint.Expect100Continue (false) didn't fix an issue. Even a 5sec timeout before getting response (thought in case of a big file it doesn't uploads so quick) didn't help.
Content type "octet-stream" was chosen by purpose to upload any file (could use some switch for most popular jpg/zip/rar/doc etc., but that one seems universal). Boundary is generated randomly from timer ticks, not a big deal. What else? :/
I could give up and forget this, but i feel i'm pretty close to solve and **then** forget about it :P.
In case you need the whole application to run and debug - here it is (70kb, zipped C# 2.0 VS2k8 solution, no ads, no viruses) :

[@Mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?no1tlmln3yy)
[@FileQube](http://www.fileqube.com/file/RZPUGRwxE203936)
[@FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/uploader)

Comment: What do you mean with "shows main page of a host"? Can you elaborate on the actual error you get? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The page with "choose file" box and upload button : 
http://i.piccy.info/i3/74/b5/3089a82aa091a0d975b987f1bedd.png
Not a page with links to file : 
http://i.piccy.info/i3/30/48/b66db6dee2e353949bd5d5269557.png
I think something doesn't work on the step where data is sent and we get results. Redirect doesn't happen, even with AllowAutoRedirect  param = true and initialised CookieContainer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update : nope, there is no redirect.

[screenshot](http://i.piccy.info/i3/ab/2d/abb26ac7f33c80910040ba58e5f6.png)

Read [RFC2388](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) few times, rewrote the code and it finally worked (i guess the trouble was in utf-read trailing boundary instead of correct 7 bit ascii). Hooray? Nope :(. Only small files are transfered, big ones throwing "The connection was closed unexpectedly".

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  Message="The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
  Source="Uploader"
  StackTrace:
   at Uploader.Upload.ProcessUpload(String FilePath, String description, String password) in F:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Uploader\Uploader.cs:line 96
   at Uploader.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in F:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Uploader\Form1.cs:line 45
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

I know that's a bug with .net stack and few solutions exists :

1. increase both `Timeout` and `ReadWriteTimeout` of a request
2. assign `request.KeepAlive = false` and `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false`
3. set `ProtocolVersion` to `1.0`
   But neither one of them nor all of them altogether help in my case. Any ideas?

**EDIT** - Source code:

```
// .. request created, required params applied
httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; // fix 1
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false; // fix 2
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000000000; // fix 3
httpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000000; // fix 4
// .. request processed, data written to request stream
string strResponse = "";            
try
{
    using (WebResponse httpResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) // error here
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
catch (WebException exception)
{
    throw exception;
}
```

Comment: On some hosts code is working, on some not... I think i can leave the above as is. The only interesting point i have - how to implement the upload progress.

Comment: `request.KeepAlive = false and System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

"As result it returns initial upload page, not a result page with links i could parse and present to a user..."

Maybe that's just the behaviour of the upload functionality: that after the upload has finished, you can upload another file?
I think you have to call another url for the "browse for file"-page (I suppose that's the one you need).

---

**Edit**: Actually, if the server sends a "redirect" (http 3xx), that's something the browser has to handle, so if you're working with your own client application in stead of a browser, you'll have to implement redirection yourself. Here the [rfc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) for more information.

Comment: The truth is somewhere out there... The common usage scenario of a service step by step is as follows:
1) loading service front page somehost.com (actually somehost.com/index.php) ;
2) Choosing file to upload via browse and file open dialog ;
3) Checking "agree to Terms of Service" checkbox to enable upload button (in non-browser case it doesn't affect anything i guess?)
4) Hit "Upload!"
5) Wait for file to upload on the same location (just some js progressbar displayed over the form, /ignore)
6) See and copy links to file and "delete file" action. Address is somehost.com/upload.php?do=verify.

Comment: The point is to get contents of a page with links, single nor multiply file download is useless if we can't find them after upload. Calling "correct" page has logic, but "upload.php?do=verify" page is generated only after request finish and manual navigation to it gives us an error "no file chosen".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the maxRequestLength property of the httpRuntime element in the Web.config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, duplicate filename causing the issue as well. I save the file's settings in an xml file but the name setting is duplicating each other.

```
      <field name="StillImage">
        <prefix>isp_main_</prefix>
        <suffix>308</suffix>
        <width>1080</width>
        <height>1080</height>
      </field>
      <field name="ThumbnailImage">
        <prefix>isp_thumb_</prefix> // pay attention to this
        <suffix>308</suffix>
        <width>506</width>
        <height>506</height>
      </field>
      <field name="Logo">
        <prefix>isp_thumb_</prefix> // and this
        <suffix>306</suffix>
        <width>506</width>
        <height>506</height>
      </field>
```

And, **in the other case I had**, the issue is in the **file length**. Please do check the allowed file size on your server. In your script just do check this part :

```
dataStream.Write(filesBytesArray, 0, filesBytesArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

And if you dont know, just limit the file uploaded size in your frontend section ie. HTML `<input type="file">` upload element, this is [good reference for limiting file size and other filter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/700593/FileUpload-Filter-File-Type-File-Extension-File-Si).