# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a .NET application which is supposed to post data to another .NET application.
I use the following code to request the login page

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy:80/", true);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
//proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "domain"); 
// webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader
                                  (webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

but it fails on this line

```
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader
                                  (webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

with the error message :

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was 
                         closed unexpectedly.
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the server closing connection - possibly dying. Check the server (logs, eventwvr, etc) and paste server code. Alternatively you may not connect to the right box (your proxy settings, etc). What is the http status you get back (it is in the response on the exception if I remember correctly)?

Comment: to start tracking down the problem, I suggest you wrap the call in exception catching code , and print out the full stack trace.

Comment: This exception is particularly hard to track down. Please give as much information as you can if you want any reasonable answers

Comment: The stack trace from the exception give nothing more than :

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Try remove all the unused crap from your code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same exception a while ago and I remember that this happens *in some cases* due to a bug in .NET. You can work around this by setting the Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout of the request to higher values, or set KeepAlive to false.

This would only be a workaround, though, so I suggest you try to find the actual root cause before assuming anything.

I'll try to come up with some web references, in the mean time, look at
[Big files uploading (WebException: The connection was closed unexpectedly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060966/big-files-uploading-webexception-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly)

Comment: seems like we are on to something here. I now get the error message The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required. Although when I set the lengthfeild the application hangs...

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this solved the problem:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

and none of the above.

Comment: I had a an issue trying to communicate to an embedded device web service and this was the solution.

Comment: I would suggest to do that instead : `request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using .NET 2.0 or above can you enable network tracing and see what's actually happening over the wire. In that way you can get more information about this particular exception.

See following link for more details, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Seems like to possible issues:

1. You never assign the proxy you create to your HttpWebRequest

   ```
   WebProxy **proxy** = new WebProxy("http://proxy:80/", true);
   HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
   //proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "domain"); 
   // webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
   webRequest.Proxy = **WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy**;
   ```

   You should assign it like this:

   ```
   WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy:80/", true);
   HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
   webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
   ```

   (notice the difference in the last line).
2. You use port 80 on your proxy. Sure that is correct? Many proxies use port 8080.

Comment: I should probably be wondering why the answer to my problem is 11 years old. Anyhow, changing my proxy to use port 8080 fixed the problem immediately. I don't know why. These were unit tests that had been running fine under port 80 for years and suddenly stopped working. Thanks for the tip, 11 years on!

Comment: Haha. Always happy to help! - Me, 11 years ago ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue once.  My virus protection was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same error for using `http` GET for an API that used `https`. Might be of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to setup proxy settings to allow not only HTTP but HTTPS on the same port as well, because one of requests was sent by HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It was different case for me. Query was taking too long hence connection was timing out. There are five timeouts in WCF
1. Send Timeout - Default 1 min
2. Receive Timeout - Default 1 min
3. Open Timeout - Default 1 min
4. Close Timeout - Default 1 min
5. Inactivity Timeout- Default 10 min

I had set Send and Receive time out correctly but problem was due inactivity timeout as query was too long on server, WCF Service was closing channel hence it was failing to transmit back the response.
Hope this helps if you are using WCF to get response from server which takes long time to run.

Answer (score -1):

```
myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

this is the solution