# Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, webclient

I have the below code. No matter how i try, it's not connecting.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Login, Password);


ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
 (sender, cert,chain,error) => true;


client.UploadFile("MyhttpsLink", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile,"D:\\test.csv");
```

1:Expected result : I need to upload that file to my FTP link

2 : Actual result : Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459475/system-net-webexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-wa

Comment: Try default NetworkCredentials which uses the current user login.  The server may not be accepting a username and password.  Most Windows PC will not allow a remote username and password. Also check using IE menu  :  Tools : Internet Options : Advance and see if TLS is enabled.  The certificate may not be valid or installed for current user.  So check in IE Internet Options : Content : Certificates.

Comment: did you try usepassive?

Comment: @BugFinder Passive mode for Webclient? Couldn't find how to define, ik how it's done for webreqquest

Comment: Clearly you didnt google : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6c618e8-8399-425f-a02c-ac38708a5ad9/webclientuploadfileasync-and-ftp-and-active-vs-passive-mode?forum=netfxnetcom