# Web service dilemma! The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, https

I have a `.Net web service` running on a `Windows 2012 64-bit` application server, `IIS 8`.

An issue was raised by our customer a number of weeks back and we are finding it very difficult to diagnose where the problem lies!

The customer calls a method on our web service passing an XML data structure. The web method simply inserts that xml data into a SQL Server database table. The return from the web method is a string "OK".

60% of the time the customer reports no issues. But for the other 40%, they are receiving the error...

> "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
> unexpectedly."

Here's a more detailed trace from the customer's end...

> Message: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was
> closed unexpectedly. HResult: -2146233079 Source: System StackTrace:
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()   Message: Unable to read
> data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
> HResult: -2146232800 Source: System StackTrace:    at
> System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> size)

Now here's the dilemma. For those failures, we did actually receive the XML data! I have even modified the web service to write to a log file just before the method returns the "OK" value. All looks good.

We even checked the IIS logs using specific timings and the HTTP status code for such a transaction is 200. This is not a timeout issue as the database insert takes milliseconds to complete.

Is there anything else that I can check on my side?

Could it be something on the customer's end?

Appreciate any guidance that you can give :-)

Comment: It kind of sounds like their problem to me. How many other customers do you have? Can they try hitting other services like public SpaceX API from the same environment? Regardless, this sounds more like a ServerFault question than SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons causing this problem, such as setting up the below code segment before invoking the web service.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Increasing both `Timeout` and `ReadWriteTimeout` of request, and assigning the `keepAlive=false`.
Please refer to the below links for more details.
[System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459475/system-net-webexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-wa)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/246ffc07-1cab-44b5-b529-f1135866ebca/exception-quotthe-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedlyquot?forum=netfxnetcom